# html5 input date dont want the cross sign

Tags: html, date

How to control not showing the 'X' in html5 where input type = date when hover?

And I don't know why in the picture, the 'x' don't show in the `2017/12/31` input.

see the picture.

[image]

first input

```
<input type="date" name="offTime" value="2017-12-31" required="">
```

second input

```
<input type="date" name="rangeExceptStartDate" value="2017-03-02">
```

Comment: Try removing "required"  attribute!

Comment: You have to add "required" attribute for both input fields either required="" OR required="required"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For first input

```
<input type="date" name="offTime" value="2017-12-31" required="">
```

required is the key which hides `clear` button

You can use below style to hide clear button from second input

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not showing X because you mentioned it as required.

first input

```
<input type="date" name="offTime" value="2017-12-31">
```

Take out the required from first and control it in javascript code as validation.

second input

```
<input type="date" name="rangeExceptStartDate" value="2017-03-02">
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the required="" (empty) is the reason here. Try filling the required="required"

```html
<input type="date" name="offTime" value="2017-12-31" required="required">

<input type="date" name="rangeExceptStartDate" value="2017-03-02" required="required">
```